# Cleaning UINavigationController after show in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have very strange bug, that I didn't have in objective-c.

I have two navigations controller one after another. In first I have UITableView. On cell click I navigate to second controller, and with clicking back button I navigate to first navigation controller. (I don't do anything else.) My memory go up every time that I navigate to second controller but it doesn't go down when I go back.

[image]
[image]

Code that I have :

First View Controller :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}


// MARK: - Navigation 

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if  segue.identifier == "segue",
        let destination = segue.destination as? SecondViewController,
        let rowIndex = table.indexPathForSelectedRow {

        let item = allItems[rowIndex.section][rowIndex.row]

        destination.itemId = segue.id as Int?
        destination.coreDataManager = self.coreDataManager
    }

}
```

Second View Controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // reload data
    reloadData()
}

private func reloadData() {

    // We need database ready to reload data from server
    guard coreDataManager != nil else {
        print("We try to prepare view, but core data is not ready jet.")
        // stop loader
        self.loader.stopLoader()
        return
    }

    self.model = Model.init(itemId: itemId! as NSNumber!, managadContext: coreDataManager!.privateChildManagedObjectContext())
}
```

`Model` object is object from Objective-c library.

I know that this object is problematic, because if I comment out last row, the step memory graph disappear.

I use same library with same call in previous Objective-C application and I didn't have this memory leak.

I try with :

```
deinit {
    self.model = nil
}
```

but it didn't help.

How to solve this memory leak, because if you look at the graph it is quite huge. After opening 4 cells I have 187 MB memory used.

### EDIT:

I figured that `deinit {}` is never called.

SUGGESTION

---

I make coreDataManager as weak var:

```
weak var coreDataManager: CoreDataManager? // weak property of Second Controller
```

### **FULL CODE**:

Second controller

```
import UIKit
import BIModel

class SecondViewController: UIViewController  {

    // MARK: - Properties

    /// This object represent connection to database.
    weak var coreDataManager: CoreDataManager?

    /// This is a Server object that represent on witch server we try to connect.
    var currentServer: Server?

    /// This is a cube id that we would like to open in this dashboard.
    var itemId: Int? = 1193 // TODO: replace this

    /// This is a model object. This object holds all calculations, all data,...
    var model : Model?


    // MARK: - Life Cicle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // reload data
        reloadData()
    }

    private func reloadData() {

        // We need database ready to reload data from server
        guard coreDataManager != nil else {
            print("We try to prepare view, but core data is not ready jet.")
            return
        }

        guard itemId != nil else {

            return
        }

        self.model = Model.init(cubeId: currentCubeId! as NSNumber!, managadContext: coreDataManager!.privateChildManagedObjectContext())
    }

    einit {

        print("DEINIT HAPPENED")
        model = nil
    }
}
```

I clean code a little bit. This is now whole code. "DEINIT HAPPENED" is printed, but memory stack is the same.

Comment: It might be your coreDataManager in the Second View Controller holding a reference. Try changing this to be a weak var. The issue is that both First View Controller and Second View Controller contain a reference to this, so it cannot deallocate the Second View Controller.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post full code of the second controller?

Comment: I edit my code.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with this code, and if deinit is called then controller is released, and you should search for memory leak in another place. Maybe check it with Instruments and see allocations at those memory peaks. Maybe check privateChildManagedObjectContext()